# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter

Tags: java-9, scala-2.12

After installing JDK9, I get this exception when running my Scala projects. Upgrading Scala to 2.12.2 also didn't resolve my problem.

Comment: You might want to **[move to using `jaxb-api:2.3.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221811/1746118)** to solve this ideally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij: SBT-based Scala project does not build with Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381242/intellij-sbt-based-scala-project-does-not-build-with-java-9)

Comment: are you found the solution @abshar

Answer (score 33):

You can add dependencies in maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 11):

The `java.xml.bind` module is not resolved by default when running code on the module path. This means that if you depend on JAXB then you need to run with `--add-modules java.xml.bind` or else deploy JAXB on the class path (or module path).

Update: The "[Modules Shared with Java EE Not Resolved by Default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F640FA9D-FB66-4D85-AD2B-D931174C09A3)" section of JDK 9 Migration Guide provides more information on this topic.

Comment: Or `--add-modules java.se.ee`

Comment: in theory this is the solution, but how do you ask scala/sbt to add this argument when they run java?

Comment: What do you think about ```javaOptions in ThisBuild += "--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM"```

Comment: ```javaOptions in ThisBuild += "--add-modules=java.xml.bind"``` would be better. Do mind the equal sign! Tested with Java version "9.0.4"

Comment: @AeroWang did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: @ChristopherPeter no I gave up

Answer (score 0):

To add to the previous answer I would like to refer to the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43574427/3751268. I think it covers in details which is the desired way to provide libraries like the `jaxb`.

In particular for Scala, I add it like this to my `libraryDependencies`:

```
libraryDependencies += Seq("javax.xml.bind" % "jaxb-api" % "2.3.0")
```