# --add-modules only on compilation

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, java-9, maven-compiler-plugin

I'm building my project with maven and [java-9](/questions/tagged/java-9). I've added in my `pom.xml` file:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${java.version}</source>
        <target>${java.version}</target>
        <compilerArgs>
            <arg>--add-modules</arg>
            <arg>java.xml.bind</arg>
        </compilerArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But still, to run the application I have to run it like this:

```
java -jar --add-modules java.xml.bind my-app.jar
```

Is there a way to build the application, to run from the command line without `--add-modules java.xml.bind` to java command line arguments?

Comment: what I think but maybe wrong, what you did in `maven-compiler-plugin` is just for compiler `javac` which is also used by maven to compile your project, but not for runtime `java`, so you had to add `--add-modules` to java runtime `java`.

Comment: That's right, and That's why I've asked question how to run without adding `--add-modules`.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

I made [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46086920/1746118) a while ago where I answered this as an additional info to exposing non `java.se` packages in Java-9 using Maven.

The added part specifically focusses on using the standalone version of the 
`java.xml.*` APIs. To adapt to which you can probably start consuming the dependency on **[`jaxb-api:2.3.0`](https://javaee.github.io/jaxb-v2/doc/user-guide/ch02.html#a-2-3-0)** which can be loaded as a module and can be executed from the classpath as well. The change you need to make is to add the following to your dependencies list:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This way you ensure migrating to standalone APIs for the module as well as moving away from a [deprecated piece of code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2941900/is-it-wrong-to-use-deprecated-methods-or-classes-in-java)

Comment: I found [this Answer by bourgesl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48279048/642706) enabled JAXB for me on Java 10.

Comment: @BasilBourque Well, the answer was to primarily focus on the `--add-modules` Vs direct dependencies of similar modules. Agreed over resolving JAXB, there is definitely an [additional step required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426)  - the proper long-term solution suggested in the accepted answer.