# Java 9: Module java.xml.bind is not accessible in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, java-9, java-module

I migrating a maven project in **Java 8** to a **Java 9** project without any build tool in `Eclipse OxyGen 1a`.

So my **module-info.java** looks like this:

[image]

But java.xml.bind is not accessible, although its in my module path:

[image]

So what is wrong here?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j/43574427?noredirect=1#comment80650142_43574427

Comment: That module is [deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.xml.bind-summary.html).  You will need to JAXB as an external library.

Comment: @VGR But it's available in JDK9, so it must be available in Eclipse

Comment: It exists in JDK 9, but it’s not in the default module path.

Comment: I suspect Eclipse is just not fully ready yet for Java 9

Comment: `requires java.xml.bind` should work. As noted by others, the module is deprecated-for-removal in Java SE but this module leads a double life and so will live on if jettisoned from the JDK. The standalone version, as of version 2.3.0, is an explicit module that you can deploy on the module path (or upgrade module path to override the version in the JDK). To your question, if it works outside of Eclipse then it hints of something in the Eclipse environment.

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46221811/1746118) for the migration of these API's.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When compiling an unnamed module, `java.xml.bind` is not accessible by default, but in a modular project (as in this question) failing to resolve reference to module `java.xml.bind` was <strike>[a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/526054)</strike> *(see edit below)*.

To work around this until the bug is fixed, you can explicitly **include** module `java.xml.bind` by double click on `Is modular` (see screenshot in the question), and in the dialog that shows, move the desired module from `Available modules` to `Explicitly included modules`:

[image: Module properties dialog]

**Edit**: <strike>[Bug 526054](https://bugs.eclipse.org/526054)</strike> has been resolved in Eclipse Oxygen.2, and thus a modular project should no longer need the steps above *(which are still relevant for code in an unnamed module, though)*.

**Edit 2**: In Eclipse 2019-06 the UI for tasks like above has been [revamped](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.12/jdt.php#buildpath-module-dependencies). Up-to-date documentation can be found in the [online help](https://help.eclipse.org/2019-06/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-properties-build-path.htm#module-dependencies).

Comment: I see a downvote and the answer has not been accepted, which let's me ask: what do you see missing?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Other projects required my attention. So to this issue: it turned out to be a mix of some eclipse problems in combination with jdk9 or newer (just like you already mentioned). Especially when using multi version jars containing builds for different jdks.
This SHOULD be fixed in eclipse by now. Will give it a new try in the comming days.
No idea why i can't mark your answer as the correct answer though...