# Can't use package javax.xml.bind from JAXB API 2.3.0

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

I'm trying to use classes from package javax.xml.bind (in jar file that I downloaded using maven : jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar) to convert between java object and XML file on eclipse using JDK9.

When I run my program, it throws an exception like that :

```
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on 
module path or classpath. - with linked exception:
[java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory
```

I found out that package javax.xml.bind contained in module java.xml.bind on JDK System Libray is deprecated since JDK9.

It tooks me like hours to find a way to remove deprecated module and to start using jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar but nothing worked out.

Could you guys help me on this? Thank you in advance.

I got here [Implementation of JAXB-API has not been found on module path or classpath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46875741/implementation-of-jaxb-api-has-not-been-found-on-module-path-or-classpath) same question but no answers so far.