# Eclipse classnotfoundexception with imported jar files

Tags: eclipse, classnotfoundexception

I've just plainly imported the jar files and this error has appeared. I've tried multiple ways online but couldn't solve it.

[image: see picture 1]

This is the classpath that i've imported.

[image: see picture 2]

Comment: There is a warning on your import statements - what does the waring say?

Comment: just some of the package are not used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JDK 9, the module `java.corba` which contains the interface `org.omg.CORBA.portable.IDLEntity` [is not resolved by default](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F640FA9D-FB66-4D85-AD2B-D931174C09A3) and has to be manually added:

**Add the module `java.corba` to the *Explicitly included modules*** as [described in this answer for `java.xml.bind`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862075/6505250) or use a Java 8 JRE/JDK.

See [blog post *Prepare for JDK 9* by Yolande Poirier](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/prepare-for-java-se-9) (emphasis by me):

> Six Java EE libraries in JDK are no longer shared by default in JDK 9.
>   Those Java EE deprecated APIs are **`java.corba`**, `java.transaction`,
>   `java.activation`, `java.xml.bind`, `java.xml.ws`, `java.xml.ws.annotation`.
>   They have been **deprecated** in JDK 9 and will be removed in a future
>   release. They are disabled by default in JDK 9. Their packages will
>   not compile in Java 9 and give an error message. The [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F640FA9D-FB66-4D85-AD2B-D931174C09A3)
>   gives you migration options to enable those libraries in JDK 9. This
>   should be a temporary solution because they are scheduled **to be
>   removed in a future release**.

Comment: I used a Java 8 JRE & the issue is solved ! Thank you