# Eclipse Oxygen plug-in Missing Constraint: Import-Package

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am writing a plug-in for Eclipse Oxygen that allows External Tools to be run directly from toolbar buttons. When I right click the project and click Run As Eclipse Application I get a pop-up that shows the following errors

```
javax.xml.ws
    Missing Constraint: Import-Package: java.xml.bind; version="0.0.0"
    Missing Constraint: Import-Package: java.xml.bind.annotation; version="0.0.0"
org.apache.xmlrpc
    Missing Constraint: Import-Package: java.xml.bind; version="0.0.0"
```

If I click Continue, Eclipse launches with the plug-in and it operates correctly. I have tried following the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1108681/2766265) to open the 'Run Configuration' and select 'Add Required Bundles' (although using Add Required Plug-ins as there is no bundles button) but it doesn't help. I neither can see *javax.xml.bind* in the list nor a way to add it.

The project itself is very simple with the following dependencies

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime
org.eclipse.debug.ui
org.eclipse.jface
```

and extensions

```
org.eclipse.debug.core.launchers
org.eclipse.ui.commands
org.eclipse.ui.handlers
org.eclipse.ui.menus
```

I have listed the dependency hierarchy and *javax.xml.bind* is not listed.

How can I add the dependencies or clear the errors?

Comment: If using Java 9, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47795587/6505250 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/46862075/6505250

Comment: @howlger. I have checked but both the project and eclipse itself are configured for Java 8. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The question is, do you use a Java 9 JRE/JDK to run it (see _JRE_ tab in the launch configuration)?

Comment: No. It is set to run with Java 8. It does export and work fine so it might not be related to my specific project. This is my first attempt at a plug-in.

Comment: I see. So the issue is that these two packages are missing in your target platform. Does adding the `javax.xml.bind` plug-in to your target platform fix your problem? You can download the plug-in from Eclipse Orbit, e. g. http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20170919201930/

Comment: That fixed it. Thank you very much. If you want to post it as a an answer I will accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems, these two packages (`java.xml.bind` and `java.xml.bind.annotation`) are missing in your target platform.

**Adding the `javax.xml.bind` plug-in** (which [can be download from Eclipse Orbit](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/), e. g. [here](http://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20170303204511/repository/plugins/javax.xml.bind_2.2.0.v201105210648.jar)) to your target platform should  fix the problem.

Comment: @PéturIngiEgilsson Does in your case the pop-up shows exactly the same message? If not, please ask a separate question with information about the Eclipse and Java version you are using for your product. If you still use Oxygen, please upgrade.

Comment: I added javax.xml.stream from https://download.eclipse.org/tools/orbit/downloads/drops/R20190827152740/repository , that solved my problem.