# Intellij: SBT-based Scala project does not build with Java 9

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, java-9

I've tried to switch my Scala/sbt based project to Java 9.
If I compile the project with sbt, it works.

If I try to build the project with the Build option of IntelliJ, I get immediately the error

```
Error:Module 'xyz' production: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
```

I've tried to add the module as dependency

```
libraryDependencies += "javax.xml.bind" % "jaxb-api" % "2.3.0"
```

and added in the compiler settings of IntelliJ (javac as well the scala compiler)

```
  <option name="ADDITIONAL_OPTIONS_STRING" value="--add-modules java.xml.bind" />
```

but does not help, unfortunately.

Comment: [Is scala ready to adapt to JDK-9?](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/139)

Comment: @nullpointer: It seems, not: https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/139

So, I was too quick...I just assumed it's ready, since compiling with sbt has worked. If you want, make an answer out of your comment

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Open [*File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment ->
   Compiler*]
2. Add "*--add-modules **java.se.ee***" to [*Shared build process VM options*]

Comment: what if I don't have Intellij but is using sbt?

Answer (score 6):

Moving this as an answer to serve as a temporary suggestion unless there is a definite solution to it and to club together few other points.

Seems like [scala](/questions/tagged/scala) is not yet complete in terms of readiness to be used with JDK-9 as visible at [scala/scala-dev - Support JDK 9](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/139)

---

On the other hand, the way of solving the dependency on the `javax.xml.bind` could be currently categorized into two categories:-

- Your project uses a library which in turn `requires javax.xml.bind`, in which case there is not much in your hands other than waiting for that library to move to a modular structure prior to your restructuring. However, this can then be temporarily hacked by the `--add-modules javax.xml.bind` option provided as the compiler argument.
- Your project makes use of the `javax.xml.bind` directly. In which case the ideal solution is to move away from the module and make use of the dependency[`jaxb-api:2.3.0`] and refactor code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @nullpointer answer, short instruction how to use `--add-modules`

Open `File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler`,
and add `--add-modules java.xml.bind` to `Shared build process VM options`

[image]

Comment: does this work for you ? I get "Error occurred during initialization of boot layerjava.lang.module.FindException: Module javax.xml.bind not found" if i try to recompile. I've added libraryDependencies += "javax.xml.bind" % "jaxb-api" % "2.3.0" in sbt.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answers.

If you are not using IntelliJ and running the program from sbt console, I found the following resolved the issue:

- Adding the following to your build.sbt:

  libraryDependencies += "javax.xml.bind" % "jaxb-api" % "2.3.0"
- Adding the import statement to your controller:

  import javax.xml._