# How will Java 9 Jigsaw Affect Normal Maven/Gradle Java apps?

Tags: java, maven, java-platform-module-system

I've read and performed all the exercises in the [Jigsaw quickstart](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jigsaw/quick-start)

I also notice that all my existing Maven/Gradle/SBT Java Projects seem to work as normal under Java 9 without any changes or benefits. Nothing is defining or using Java Jigsaw Modules.

Is the normal Java/JVM world of Maven/Gradle/SBT going to adopt Jigsaw in a more noticeable way? Are all the libraries and frameworks of the JVM world going to use Jigsaw? Is there a reason or benefit over the Maven-dependency system that exists today? Is there any point or benefit for normal Java developers to use Jigsaw at all?

**EDIT**: I've read several StackOverflow questions with these search terms and none of them addressed my question. The linked StackOverflow question is from well over a year ago about an error with Maven 3.3 against early builds of JDK 9. That is completely irrelevant. I'm not getting errors. Also, Maven 3.5 and the final JDK 9 are out at the time of this posting.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381242/intellij-sbt-based-scala-project-does-not-build-with-java-9/46383089#46383089.. or https://stackoverflow.com/q/36583118/1746118??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is Maven ready for JDK9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36583118/is-maven-ready-for-jdk9)

Comment: Jigsaw has some advantages like stronger encapsulation which can be relevant for normal Java developers as well. In my opinion, the possibility to export only defined packages to users to a JAR is quite useful for normal developers as well.

But the main question, if libraries and frameworks are going to use it, is quite speculative and only time will tell. In my opinion, they are going to use it eventually, but others may have other opinions...