# Scala incompatibility with Java 9 - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, sbt, java-9

Just run a sample Scala SBT project after installing Java 9 on my pc and I took this exception.
I already tried some solutions that I found but nothing.

Is there any incompatibility between Java 9 and Scala?

Scala Version: 2.12.3

Java Version: java version "9"

IDE: IntelliJ

Thanks in advance.

```
info] Compiling 7 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/ermis/Projects/begining-scala/target/scala-2.12/classes...
[info] p.a.h.EnabledFilters - Enabled Filters (see <https://www.playframework.com/documentation/latest/Filters>):

play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter
play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter
play.filters.hosts.AllowedHostsFilter

[info] play.api.Play - Application started (Dev)
Uncaught error from thread [play-dev-mode-akka.actor.default-
dispatcher-2]: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter, shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for for ActorSystem[play-dev-mode]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.Base64Codec.decode(Base64Codec.java:26)
    at io.jsonwebtoken.impl.DefaultJwtBuilder.signWith(DefaultJwtBuilder.java:106)
    at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec$JWTFormatter.format(Cookie.scala:710)
    at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec.encode(Cookie.scala:569)
    at play.api.mvc.JWTCookieDataCodec.encode$(Cookie.scala:567)
    at play.api.mvc.DefaultJWTCookieDataCodec.encode(Cookie.scala:760)
    at play.api.mvc.FallbackCookieDataCodec.encode(Cookie.scala:734)
    at play.api.mvc.FallbackCookieDataCodec.encode$(Cookie.scala:733)
    at play.api.mvc.DefaultSessionCookieBaker.encode(Session.scala:95)
    at play.api.mvc.CookieBaker.encodeAsCookie(Cookie.scala:414)
    at play.api.mvc.CookieBaker.encodeAsCookie$(Cookie.scala:413)
    at play.api.mvc.DefaultSessionCookieBaker.encodeAsCookie(Session.scala:95)
    at play.api.mvc.Result.$anonfun$bakeCookies$2(Results.scala:281)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:146)
    at play.api.mvc.Result.bakeCookies(Results.scala:280)
    at play.core.server.common.ServerResultUtils.prepareCookies(ServerResultUtils.scala:227)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.$anonfun$executeAction$3(AkkaHttpServer.scala:302)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.strictTransform$1(FastFuture.scala:41)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.transformWith$extension1(FastFuture.scala:55)
    at akka.http.scaladsl.util.FastFuture$.flatMap$extension(FastFuture.scala:26)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.executeAction(AkkaHttpServer.scala:301)
    at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer.executeHandler(AkkaHttpServer.scala:254)
```

I tried this but didn't work.

--add-modules java.xml.bind 
or
--add-modules java.se.ee
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellij: SBT-based Scala project does not build with Java 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381242/intellij-sbt-based-scala-project-does-not-build-with-java-9). Would Retract the vote if the question is edited to explain what all from the current solutions didn't help. @pkont Please tag me for such a case. Otherwise, would delete the answer if closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a compiler option to temporarily fix this:

```
--add-modules java.se.ee
```

since the [Module shared by Java EE would not be resolved by default in JDK9.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/migrate/toc.htm#JSMIG-GUID-F640FA9D-FB66-4D85-AD2B-D931174C09A3)

You can also keep track of the issue to [Support JDK 9](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/139)  at scala-dev repository for updates as well.

Comment: I tried both of them but didn't work.

--add-modules java.xml.bind

--add-modules java.se.ee

Comment: @pkont Did you try `--add-modules java.se.ee` individually? What error did you get still?

Comment: same as the previous case

Comment: @pkont and how about `--add-modules ALL-SYSTEM`?

Comment: @pkont Actually I think I found a duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46381242/intellij-sbt-based-scala-project-does-not-build-with-java-9, does none of the solution mentioned there work? If not, then update the question with that information, please.

Comment: actually it should be `--add-modules java.xml.bind`, others from `java.se.ee` module are quite inferior to real implementations

Comment: @KrzysztofKrasoń Ya..actually my initial suggestion on the [linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46383089/1746118), would await for OP to revert to it. I have voted this as a duplicate wither ways.

Comment: This worked for me. It has to be added to `Shared build process VM options`, just search for that in the preferences dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I just remove Java 9 until someone gives me some lights and the compile works as usual.