# Maven Java Compile

Tags: java, maven, jar, executable-jar

I'm new to Maven and Java but when in search for a good EID reader this looked like the best choice (https://github.com/grakic/jfreesteel/).
I've ran "mvn install" and made the .jar file which when ran resulted in:

- The terminal waiting for me to insert the card
- When the card is inserted the terminal recognises it and continues .
- And finally it crashes

This is the full log of what happens:

```
[main] INFO net.devbase.jfreesteel.nativemessaging.EidWebExtensionApp - Starting web extensions native messaging background app...
[main] INFO net.devbase.jfreesteel.nativemessaging.EidWebExtensionApp - Using terminal factory type PC/SC
[Thread-0] INFO net.devbase.jfreesteel.nativemessaging.EidWebExtensionApp - Card inserted
[Thread-0] INFO net.devbase.jfreesteel.EidCard - exclusive
[Thread-0] INFO net.devbase.jfreesteel.EidCard - exclusive free
[Thread-0] INFO net.devbase.jfreesteel.EidCard - photo exclusive
[Thread-0] INFO net.devbase.jfreesteel.EidCard - photo exclusive free
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter
    at net.devbase.jfreesteel.Utils.image2Base64String(Utils.java:220)
    at net.devbase.jfreesteel.nativemessaging.EidWebExtensionApp.inserted(EidWebExtensionApp.java:261)
    at net.devbase.jfreesteel.nativemessaging.EidWebExtensionApp.access$400(EidWebExtensionApp.java:25)
    at net.devbase.jfreesteel.nativemessaging.EidWebExtensionApp$2.run(EidWebExtensionApp.java:155)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: Which version of Java are you using? If using 1.5 or older, then try with 1.6 or later version and see it resolves your issue.

Comment: @Ramu it says that Java SE 1.7 is recommended, but i'm using Java SE 13. 
I've looked here (https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/archive-139210.html) , but i don't see 1.7, am i missing anythin?

Comment: Thanks for confirming the java version. The reason you are seeing this error is, From Java 9, JAXB classes are **not** added by default with java. See the following post. [DatatypeConverter Class Not Found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966880/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-datatypeconverter/42971683) . Fix is, you can either use java 1.7 or 1.8 or add jaxb dependency to the jfreesteel project's pom.xml.